# How can I get the span tag value which has the same class name and Created dynamically using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the span tag text which I created dynamically at runtime.

My task is I want to get the file path name

```js
$(document).on('click', '.MainFolder', function () {
        // Your Code
        var $self = $(this);
        
        var parentPath = $(this).children('.pathValue').text();
        alert('childrent = ' + $(this).children('.pathValue').text());
        $('.SubFolder').css("background", "none");
        

        $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtPath_I').val(parentPath);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            url: "adminCopyCrystalReport.aspx/getDirectoryNames",

            data: JSON.stringify({
                "dirLocation": $(this).children('.pathValue').text()
            }),

            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert('Success = '+data.d);
                for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                    $('<div class="MainFolder"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close folder-icon"></span>' + data.d[i] + '<span style="visibility: visible;" class="pathValue">' + parentPath + data.d[i] + '/</span></div>').appendTo($self);
                }
                //$self = "";
                //parentPath = "";
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="MainFolder" style="padding-left: 20px; width: 200px;">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close folder-icon"></span>Folder1<br>
  <span style="visibility: visible;" class="pathValue">~/MyDocuments/Folder1/</span>
</div>
<div class="MainFolder" style="padding-left: 20px; width: 200px;">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close folder-icon"></span>Folder2<br>
  <span style="visibility: visible;" class="pathValue">~/MyDocuments/Folder2/</span>
</div>
```

On page load it will show the result like belo

```
Folder1

~/MyDocuments/Folder1/             //File Path                              

Folder2

~/MyDocuments/Folder2/
```

When User click on **Folder1**, I will call ajax and pass the corresponding url and it will get the subfolder name

```
Folder1

~/MyDocuments/Folder1/             //File Path     

    SubFolder1
    ~/MyDocuments/Folder1/SubFolder1   
    SubFolder2
    ~/MyDocuments/Folder1/SubFolder1
    SubFolder3                      
    ~/MyDocuments/Folder1/SubFolder1   

Folder2

~/MyDocuments/Folder2/
```

**Until this, it is working fine.**

When I select `SubFolder1` or `SubFolder2` or `SubFolder3`, that click function is calling two times, And giving the same file name like below

```
Folder1
    SubFolder1
    SubFolder2
    SubFolder3                      
    SubFolder1
    SubFolder2
    SubFolder3                      

Folder2
```

**Update**

When I click on `SubFolder1`, on my alert it is printing like below

First alert:   childrent = ~/MyDocuments/Folder1/SubFolder1/

Second alert:   childrent = ~/MyDocuments/Folder1/

and then It is calling ajax url and calling two times with those two url's. **But my first url is correct**. I don't want to get the second url.

Comment: After appending to self, `.MainFolder` would increase height. It causes AJAX being triggered multi times. The subfolder's parent `.MainFolder` fires first and then comes another from its parent's folder's `.MainFolder`.

Comment: Didn't give it a test since I can't access the url. But you can try to replace `.MainFolder` with `.pathValue` in delegate event handler.

Comment: @Hikarunomemory What do you mean `.MainFolder would increase height`?.. But you are correct, it calls `subfolder` first, then again it calls the `Parent folder`. How can I overcome this?

Comment: @Hikarunomemory Can you give me a sample code to understand better?.

Answer (score 0):

To show the difference clearly, the area that can be clicked set as a red square.

This is a simple demo showing why AJAX triggered multi times.

```js
var fakeSubFolder = '<div class="MainFolder"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close folder-icon"></span><span style="visibility: visible;" class="pathValue">' + 'SubFolder' + '/</span></div>'

$(document).on('click', '.MainFolder', function() {
  var $self = $(this)
  $(fakeSubFolder).appendTo($self);
});
```

```css
.MainFolder{
  outline: 1px red solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="MainFolder" style="padding-left: 20px; width: 200px;">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close folder-icon"></span>Folder1<br>
  <span style="visibility: visible;" class="pathValue">~/MyDocuments/Folder1/</span>
</div>
<div class="MainFolder" style="padding-left: 20px; width: 200px;">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close folder-icon"></span>Folder2<br>
  <span style="visibility: visible;" class="pathValue">~/MyDocuments/Folder2/</span>
</div>
```

And here's a demo showing how to overcome.

```js
var fakeSubFolder = '<div class="MainFolder"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close folder-icon"></span><span style="visibility: visible;" class="pathValue">' + 'SubFolder' + '/</span></div>'

$('body').on('click', '.pathValue', function() {
  var $self = $(this)
  var $parent = $self.parent()
  $(fakeSubFolder).appendTo($parent);
});
```

```css
.pathValue{
  outline: 1px red solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="MainFolder" style="padding-left: 20px; width: 200px;">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close folder-icon"></span>Folder1<br>
  <span style="visibility: visible;" class="pathValue">~/MyDocuments/Folder1/</span>
</div>
<div class="MainFolder" style="padding-left: 20px; width: 200px;">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close folder-icon"></span>Folder2<br>
  <span style="visibility: visible;" class="pathValue">~/MyDocuments/Folder2/</span>
</div>
```

Comment: That `pathValue` i will not visible to user at all. I will hide. I don't want to show to end user

Comment: you are almost correct, Anyway, thank you bro for spending time with me.